# When working in C++/cli, I cannot add a Nuget package targeting a managed project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, castle

While creating a Mouse and Keyboard automation suite, I attempted to move my C# developed code using lots of p/invokes to a managed C++/cli project.
 Unfortunately when attempting to add the nuget package Castle.Core it causes an issue when Visual Studio 2015 tries to load the package into my project.

What I have looked into:
I found that some internal specifics to nuget packages have to be set up in such a way that a "native" project can load the resources. However, shouldn't the package be loaded anyway since the project is technically not native but instead a mix of both native and managed? Is this a bug, is it fixed in newer versions of VS or if VS isn't the offender, what part is exactly?

Other considerations: ILMerge, Netmodules. These may help me in such a way that I can create another C# project (this would be public facing) that I can load all the managed nuget packages into so that then I can use the interface I need in my public methods. I can make all methods in my C++/cli project private (maybe) and access those internally from my public C# class methods.

Anyway, I would just like to know what I can do to come up with a single dll that has all the functionality I need while hopefully not p/invoking a rather large amount of things that would frankly just be easier to simply use in a C++/cli project instead.

Comment: Castle.Core depends on .net Standard 1.3 and c++/cli isn't compatible with .net Standard.

Comment: Nuget does not know anything about C++/CLI projects.  They only ever added support for native C++ projects, there isn't anything similar to Castle for C++.  Consider using a dummy C# project to obtain the assembly so you can add a reference to it.

Comment: Ok, excellent answer Hans Passant, thank you.